# On the fontspring bulletproof @font-face syntax... what goes after the #?

Tags: syntax, font-face

I've seen several examples of the bulletproof syntax. I took this from the original article at fontspring:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

What exactly is supposed to go after the **svg#** ?
"svg font name" is about the filename? the font-family declaration? what if my font family has spaces?

Answer (score 4):

The #svgFontName is referencing the Font ID embedded inside the svg font file. So, for example, you may have something like this in your svg document:

```
<font id="example-font-name" horiz-adv-x="512">
```

Where *"example-font-name"* should be referenced inside your CSS @font-face like this:

```
url('myfont-webfont.svg#example-font-name') format('svg');
```

The SVG font adds support for Legacy iOS, so it's not extremely important. Take a look inside your SVG font file by opening it up in any text editor and look for a Font ID towards the top of your document. Let me know if you have any questions!